# AFNetworking returns 200 when should receive 304 - ETag

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, etag

I'm tring to use the etag to cache my images, the first time it downloads all the images like it should however the second time it does too when it should enter the failed block with 304.

I've tried making the request externally and I get 304 like I should, it's just with AFNetworking that i'm having trouble

```
   NSString *urlString = [API_BASE_URL_PHOTOS stringByAppendingPathComponent:[photo getPathToPhoto]];
    NSString *properlyEscapedURL = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:properlyEscapedURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    if ([UserDefaultManager getEtagForKey:photo.nom] != nil) {
        [request setValue:[UserDefaultManager getEtagForKey:photo.nom] forHTTPHeaderField:ETAG_IF_NONE_MATCH];
    } 
    [request setHTTPMethod:API_METHOD_GET];

AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request imageProcessingBlock:nil
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

    [FileUtils createDirectoryInDocumentsWithFileName:photo.folderName];
    NSString *docPath = [FileUtils getPathInDocumentsWithFileName:[photo getPathToPhoto]];

    // Save Image
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
    [imageData writeToFile:docPath atomically:YES];


    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
        NSDictionary *allHeaderFields = [response allHeaderFields];
        [UserDefaultManager setEtag:[allHeaderFields objectForKey:ETAG] forKey:photo.nom];
    }


    if ([[DownloadManager sharedManager].downloadQueue.operations count] == 0) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_DOWNLOAD_ALL_PHOTOS_FINISHED object:nil];
    }
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (response.statusCode != RESPONSE_CODE_PHOTO_UP_TO_DATE) {
        LogDebug(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}];
```

Comment: If you make the request externally and get a 304, and you make it in AFNetworking and get a 200, you are probably making the request differently.  AFNetworking doesn't contain any code that would change the HTTP status code your server returns.

Comment: yeah, I managed to figure it out, I changed my request to

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                           timeoutInterval:10];

and that did the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing my request to

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                           timeoutInterval:60];
```

hope that this helps

Comment: The default timeout interval for NSURLRequest is 60 seconds; I'd stick to that unless you have a reason you switched to 10.

Comment: thanks, I changed it to 60, it was set to 10 in the example that I saw